# Use different sbt-web SettingKey values when running `stage` and `run`

Tags: playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager, sbt-web

I am writing an SBT plugin. In the plugin, I have:

`val prod = SettingKey[Boolean]("prod", "This will minify stuffs.")`

In `build.sbt` of a project that uses this plugin, I want to set different values when running `sbt stage` and `sbt run`.

I've tried many different combinations, and they don't work (e.g. `prod in Assets in stage := true`).

I wonder if anyone knows how to solve this problem. It seems like a normal problem that should have been easily solved with scoping, but I don't understand SBT's scope that well.

If you have a small example on how to override SettingKey when running different commands, it would be great. Thank you.

Comment: You could reuse sbt-web-scalajs's approach. A clue: https://github.com/vmunier/sbt-web-scalajs/blob/master/src/main/scala/webscalajs/WebScalaJS.scala#L29

Comment: Could you make your comment an answer? After I've tried many combination, your suggestion, though looking a bit hacky to me, is the best one. I thought there would be a way to override scope and etc. I thought wrong. Thank you for your suggestion.